# Is the measurable transformation of stationary ergodic sequence also ergodic?

Tags: probability-theory, ergodic-theory, stationary-processes

Let $X_n$ be a stationary and ergodic sequence. Let function $f:R \to R $ be measurable. Is it true that the sequnce $f(X_n)$ would be also ergodic?

If no, than for which $f$ it holds? (Continuous? Bounded?)

I understand that this question should be basic, but was not able to find anywhere the idea of how to proof it.

Comment: Obviously yes, provided that you use the induced measure. Solution: make the change of variables and find the induced measure. Then the averages coincide.